# Busca/cadastro de objeto via url REST e cadastro com SPRING

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, restful, spring-boot

Sou iniciante com REST e Spring.
Estou fazendo um exercício onde tenho que buscar um cliente via url e retornar(GET) ele no formato JSON e inserir(POST) um cliente no formato JSON.

Para buscar sera no modelo abaixo, usando GET:

```
http://localhost:8080/clientes/?nome=paulo
```

e retornar:

```
{
     "nome": "paulo",
     "cpf": 1231243434,
     "idade": 34,
     "sexo": M,
}
```

para inserir no modelo usando POST:

```
{
     "nome": "paulo",
     "cpf": 1231243434,
     "idade": 34,
     "sexo": M,
}
```

Isto utilizando somente a memória dos objetos instanciados.

Minhas classes:

Cliente

```
package model;
public class Cliente {

private String nome;
private String cpf;
private Integer idade;
private String sexo;

public Cliente(String nome, String cpf, Integer idade, String sexo) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.idade = idade;
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public Integer getIdade() {
    return idade;
}

public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cliente [nome=" + nome + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", idade=" +   idade + ", sexo=" + sexo + "]";
}
}
```

ClienteController

```
package controller;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import model.Cliente;
import service.ClienteService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clientes")
public class ClienteController {


@Autowired
ClienteService cli;

@RequestMapping("/all")
public Hashtable<String, Cliente> getAll(){
    return cli.getAll();
}

//não esta buscando desta forma
@RequestMapping("{nome}")
public Cliente getCliente(@PathVariable("nome") String nome){   
    return cli.getCliente(nome);
}
}
```

ClienteService

```
package service;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import model.Cliente;

@Service
public class ClienteService {
Hashtable<String, Cliente> clientes = new Hashtable<String, Cliente>      ();

public ClienteService(){

    Cliente c1 = new Cliente("paulo","123.123.123-22",28,"M");
    Cliente c2 = new Cliente("diego","123.123.123-22",24,"M");
    Cliente c3 = new Cliente("Debora","123.123.123-22",21,"F");

    clientes.put("1", c1);
    clientes.put("2", c2);
    clientes.put("3", c3);

}

public Cliente getCliente(String nome){
    if(clientes.containsKey(nome)){
        return clientes.get(nome);
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
public Hashtable<String, Cliente> getAll(){
    return clientes;
}

}
```

Até o momento ja consegui mostrar todos os clientes instanciados no formato JSON, ja fiz algumas pesquisas e não estou conseguindo resolver isto.

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando fazer uma consulta por **query param** (`clientes?nome=paulo`) mas implementou uma busca por **path param**. (`clientes/paulo`)

Tente alterar sua busca para:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Cliente getCliente(@RequestParam("nome") String nome){   
    return cli.getCliente(nome);
}
```

E, aproveitando, corrija a sua outra consulta, removendo o `all` no final. Nas boas práticas do Rest, quando você chamar um recurso sem mencionar nada, você estará pedindo por todos os recursos disponíveis. Para isto, altere desta forma:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Hashtable<String, Cliente> getAll(){
    return cli.getAll();
}
```

E faça apenas:

```
http://localhost:8080/clientes/
```

Para retornar todos os clientes

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma olhada na documentação mas para pegar um parâmetro ele usa a annotation @RequestParam.

Documentação: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(@RequestParam("petId") int petId, ModelMap model) {
        Pet pet = this.clinic.loadPet(petId);
        model.addAttribute("pet", pet);
        return "petForm";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Olá, jovem!

Você está usando "@PathVariable" no lugar de "@RequestParam".
Se for usar assim, o código deve ficar desta forma:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{nome}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Cliente getCliente(@PathVariable("nome") String nome){   
    return cli.getCliente(nome);
}
```

Aí você terá que dar o GET através da URI:

```
http://localhost:8080/clientes/paulo
```

Há outras formas de fazer isso. Se sua intenção é apenas buscar por nome mesmo, você pode atacar assim:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Cliente getCliente(@RequestParam("nome") String nome){   
    return cli.getCliente(nome);
}
```

Ou ainda pode atacar assim:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Cliente getCliente(Cliente cliente){   
    return cli.getCliente(cliente.getNome());
}
```

Para esses dois exemplos, a uri é a que você havia escrito:

```
http://localhost:8080/clientes?nome=paulo
```

No segundo caso, o próprio spring já cuida de transformar o que você manda pra cliente.
Já que você vai querer transitar Cliente, você precisa implementar Serializable.

```
public class Cliente implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Qualquer dúvida, é só perguntar

Comment: Opa muito obrigado pela ajuda Jean!

Comment: Implementei um metodo para buscar por nome e cpf so que quando executo o programa o spring me retorna erro.  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Cliente getCliente(@RequestParam("nome") String nome){ 
     return cli.getCliente(nome);
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Cliente getCpf(@RequestParam("cpf") String cpf){ 
     return cli.getCliente(cpf);
 }

Comment: Ele informa: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'clienteController' method 
public model.Cliente controller.ClienteController.getCpf(java.lang.String)
to {[/clientes],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'clienteController' bean method

Comment: @DiegoSantos, cara, como ambos os métodos tem assinaturas semelhantes, no que se refere ao roteamento, ele tá se perdendo e não sabe qual colocar pra ql.

Ambos são acessados através da mesma uri, e tem um parâmetro que receber uma string. 

Confesso que nunca tive um case assim pra resolver. Imagino que você consigo criar um bean pra cara um e boa. Eu atacaria diferente, criando uma rota específica pra cada um. Acho que fica até mais educado pra qm for consumir.

Comment: Ficaria algo como: 
´
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clientes")
public class ClienteController {
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/pesquisar/cpf/{valor}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
 public ResponseEntity<?>  getCpf(@PathVariable("valor") String cpf){
  return new ResponseEntity<>(cpf, HttpStatus.OK);
 } 
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/pesquisar/nome/{valor}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
 public ResponseEntity<?> getCliente(@PathVariable("valor") String pessoa){
  return new ResponseEntity<>(pessoa, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
} ´